# Getting logic error using JavaScript on creating like/dislike counter

Tags: javascript

I've fixed the bug. I'm documenting my code for future reference.

I'm creating a like/dislike counter and getting a logic error.

My script works such that on clicking on either button I can like/dislike or undo that action. I've tried creating logic such that when I dislike after liking the post, or vice versa, the dislike decrements and the like counter increments . The problem where I'm stuck at is after successively clicking both buttons, either one of the counter resets to zero.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var dislike_b = like_b = false;

            var num1 = 0;
            var like = parseInt("{{post.like_votes}}");

            var num2 = 0;
            var dislike = parseInt("{{post.dislike_votes}}");

            function likeHandler() {
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                if (dislike_b == true){
                    dislikeHandler();
                    //dislike_b = false ;
                }
                
                // like iterator
                like = like + (-1)**num1 ;
                num1 = (num1 + 1)%2;
                document.getElementById("like").innerHTML = like;
                like_b = !like_b;

                console.log( like , num1);

                //var catid;
                //catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/likepost/",
                        data: {
                            //post_id: catid , 
                            votes : like ,
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            //$('#like' + catid).remove();
                            $('#message').text(data);
                        }
                    })
                

            }
            


            function dislikeHandler() {
                const xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();

                if (like_b == true){
                    likeHandler();
                }
                
                // like iterator
                dislike = dislike + (-1)**num2 ;
                num2 = (num2 + 1)%2;
                document.getElementById("dislike").innerHTML = dislike;
                dislike_b = !dislike_b;

                console.log( dislike , num1);

                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/dislikepost/",
                        data: {
                            votes : dislike ,
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#message').text(data);
                        }
                    })
                

            }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried preventDefault()?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this function. I've read that it cancels all cancelable events. But the functions in my aren't suitable for this. Can you suggest where should I put it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try simplifying it a little like this by putting the ajax request in its own function. What else needs to happen when clicking the buttons? Just comment and I'll update.

```js
// Variables
let likes = 0
let dislikes = 0


// Like
function like() {
  const likeDOMText = document.querySelector('.like span')
  likes++
  likeDOMText.innerText = likes
  
  // Calling the ajax request
  initRequest({
    likes: likes,
    dislikes: dislikes,
    // And whatever else
  })
}


// Dislike
function dislike() {
  const dislikeDOMText = document.querySelector('.dislike span')
  dislikes++
  dislikeDOMText.innerText = dislikes
  
  // Calling the ajax request
  initRequest({
    likes: likes,
    dislikes: dislikes,
    // And whatever else
  })
}


// Ajax request to server
function initRequest(data) {
  // $.ajax({
    // ...
    //data: JSON.parse(data)
  //})
}
```

```html
<button class="like" onclick="like()">Like <span>0</span></button>
<button class="dislike" onclick="dislike()">Dislike <span>0</span></button>
```